# Linq statement return error when no record found

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

THe linq statement below return an exception error when no match record found. Is there anyway to handle this?, Please advise, thank you

```
AdventureEntities hem = new AdventureEntities ();
Guid productId;

Adventure.Product list= hem.Product .Where(x => x.Product== productId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it said "An error occured while processing this request" . ANd it throws the error on TotalCount which is null.

Comment: place profiler and check the call that is being executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that shouldn't throw an exception. It will, however, set `list` to `null` - because that's what `FirstOrDefault` does when there are no results.

If you then dereference `list`, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. You can avoid this by just checking for nullity first:

```
if (list != null)
{
    // Use the list
}
```

Also note that you can use the overload of `FirstOrDefault` which accepts a predicate, to make the code simpler:

```
var list = hem.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Product== productId);
```

Comment: i have implement var list = hem.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Product== productId); then an error occured said that FirstOrDefault is not supported. The weird thing it does not display error when you build the solution but it throws when you run it.

Comment: @Supermode: That's not weird at all - that's just the way that LINQ providers work. (The code is valid C# code - it's just not supported in EF apparently.) What is the type of your `Product` property? Perhaps you actually want `ProductId` or something... and what error did you get when you were using `Where`?

Comment: adding x.productId != null fixed the problem. var list = hem.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Product== productId && x.productId != null);

Comment: @Supermode: I'm glad it did, but I was more suggesting `x => x.ProductId == productId` - it might be worth trying that, too.